# Equal elements in two lists

Tags: python, python-3.x

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Determine if 2 lists have the same elements, regardless of order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8866652/determine-if-2-lists-have-the-same-elements-regardless-of-order)
>   [Match two lists of letters in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11140297/match-two-lists-of-letters-in-python)

I have list `a` and list `b`. So I need to find, if lists have equal elements. I have no idea, but I am thinking about using `collections`.

Comment: I think you're looking for [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8866652/determine-if-2-lists-have-the-same-elements-regardless-of-order).

Comment: What do you mean by "equal elements"? Does frequency matter? Does order matter?

Comment: what about a=[2,2,3] and b=[1,2,2]? Should be [2] or [2,2]? What about order?

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you don't care about order.  There are a few options here, the best solution depends on the contents of your lists.  Here are a few possibilities in order of preference (and restrictions):

- If there are no duplicates, and all items are hashable:

  ```
  set(a) == set(b)
  ```
- If there are duplicates, and all items are of the same type:

  ```
  sorted(a) == sorted(b)
  ```
- If there are duplicates and the list may have mixed types, and all types are hashable:

  ```
  collections.Counter(a) == collections.Counter(b)
  ```
- If there are duplicates, the list may have mixed types, and some elements may not be hashable (there must be a better way to do this, but what I came up with was to turn each element into a tuple with the string representation of the type, followed by the value):

  ```
  keyfunc = lambda x: (str(type(x)), x)
  sorted(a, key=keyfunc) == sorted(b, key=keyfunc)
  ```

Comment: "wrapping each element in a tuple allows ordering between different types" - are you sure? Doesn't work for me (3.2)

Comment: @thg435 Oops, I originally had `lambda x: (type(x), x)` and must have tested just wrapping the value on 2.x thinking it was 3.2 (I have a parallel installation).  It turns out that doesn't even work though, current solution is `lambda x: (str(type(x)), x)`, but there must be a better way.

Comment: How about `key=repr` (just kidding)) Otherwise, a good answer to a remarkably poor question.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> all(x in b for x in a)
```

Comment: This won't work if `a` is a smaller list. For example this will return true when `a = [0, 1]` and `b = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` but it should return false. It checks if `a` is contained within `b`, not if they are equal.